# style="left:0px; width:100%" does not fill from left to right fully in IE

Tags: css

This may sound silly.

I have a `<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:200px; background-color:#222222; margin-bottom:50px; right:0px;"></div>`.  It shows up from left to right on ff and chrome, but not IE.  How exactly should be resolved.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `right` in addition to `left`:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

Comment: This is my <div>

<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:200px; background-color:#222222; margin-bottom:50px; right:0px;">

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you need to make sure the parent element has a width set.  If the parent is the body tag, just give it the same 100% width value:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

or using style attributes only:

```
<body style="width:100%;">
  <div 
    style="left:0px; width:100%; top:0px; position:absolute; background-color:#000">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to be able to set up a div, to be 100%, so the body with width tag will not help

Comment: @Jean: I don't think you understand what I mean.  The parent element of your 100% wide div **also** needs to have `width` defined in IE.  I was just using `body` as an example.

Comment: Here is my div

<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:200px; background-color:#222222; margin-bottom:50px; right:0px;"></div>

Comment: tried this

<style>
body{width:100%;}
</style>

does not work